# wrong number of arguments (4 for 3) for `rgb' issue in css.scss file in rails 3.2.13

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass

**rgb wrong number of arguments issue in rails:**

I saw that rgb in css file takes 3 arguments as mentioned here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp

But in my project abc.css.scss file have code like this

```
border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100, 2);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.1);
```

So what is happening here. Am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: mmmmm @musefan I know that my friend :) but this project is pre started by someone else and there was code. SO I'm little bit confused  am I missing something and what to do with 4th parameter? what was the use of that.

Answer (score 29):

The short and sweet answer is when you use `rgb` you can't pass an alpha property. Use `rgba` to use `alpha`

Answer (score 12):

The 4th parameter is for `alpha`

So for example `rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);`

Here `.1` is alpha/opacity

Why he is declaring the proper twice?

```
border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100, 2); 
/* This is fall back if browser doesn't support `rgba` but 
   here the 4th parameter shouldn't be there, it's making the proerty useless.. */

border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
/* Here he is having black color with an alpha of .2 */
```

So having `rgb` with 4 parameters makes the property value invalid, hence you need to remove the last parameter from `rgb` in your first property

Comment: yeah but that is between 0 and 1, but here is 2 at first line. What to do with thaat?

Answer (score 9):

The answer is quite self explanatory. `rgb` expects 3 arguments, so you need to give it 3, not 4.

This is what you want:

```
border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.1);
```

Notice that the first line has changed

If you keep the 4th parameter, that first line of code will not work. It will simply be ignored and have no effect.

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jRcPr/): You will notice the square is black, because the `rgb` with the 4th parameter is invalid and is therefore not applied

Comment: So you are saring to drop that one. I'm here to discuss is there any significance of that 4th parameter as there are so many 4th parameter in rgb :)

Comment: Yes, get rid of it. It would do anything

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()_and_rgba()), browsers that support CSS Colors Level 4 do act exactly as the OP intended.  The 4th argument is optional, and apparently defaults to 1, though I don't see the default value specifically documented anywhere at this time.
So what browsers support this?

caniuse.com has an indirect indicator, RGBA hex notation, [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa). It looks pretty positive at >75% as of today, but my limited testing shows that support for the CSS rgb function's 4th arg is less than that.  I have created a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/vzdRym), which works in the latest Firefox and Chrome on Windows, and in Chrome for Android 7. It also verifies that the default value for the 4th arg is 1. This is the CSS:

```
body {
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 0, 153.6, 0),  rgb(255, 0, 153.6) 100%);
}
```

If you see the opacity change from 0 to 1, left to right, then it's working.
It does not work on Chrome or Safari on iOS 11. But [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/GXQxBx), using hex notation does work in all 5 environments I've tested. Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  background:linear-gradient(90deg, #FF009900,  #FF0099 100%);
}
```

Does anyone have more specific information about this aspect of CSS Colors Level 4 and its support? I've added two codepens to separate tests for the [4th arg](https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/BOYxKE) and [numbers with decimals](https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/VGQxjx). The 2 browsers on iOS 11 don't support either.

Answer (score 0):

In Sass, `rgb()` and `rgba()` are functions that create a variable with the type *color*.  When compiled to CSS, it looks identical to the function syntax.  The *color* type is necessary to make it eligible to be used with the color manipulating functions (lighten(), darken(), etc.).

https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/ab4b3b918bfa1fc77a9c4378e199ca1ed6f1704c/lib/sass/script/functions.rb#L366

```
# Creates a {Color} object from red, green, and blue values.
#
# @param red [Number]
#   A number between 0 and 255 inclusive,
#   or between 0% and 100% inclusive
# @param green [Number]
#   A number between 0 and 255 inclusive,
#   or between 0% and 100% inclusive
# @param blue [Number]
#   A number between 0 and 255 inclusive,
#   or between 0% and 100% inclusive
# @see #rgba
# @return [Color]
def rgb(red, green, blue)
  assert_type red, :Number
  assert_type green, :Number
  assert_type blue, :Number

  Color.new([red, green, blue].map do |c|
      v = c.value
      if c.numerator_units == ["%"] && c.denominator_units.empty?
        v = Sass::Util.check_range("Color value", 0..100, c, '%')
        v * 255 / 100.0
      else
        Sass::Util.check_range("Color value", 0..255, c)
      end
    end)
end
declare :rgb, [:red, :green, :blue]

# @see #rgb
# @overload rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)
#   Creates a {Color} object from red, green, and blue values,
#   as well as an alpha channel indicating opacity.
#
#   @param red [Number]
#     A number between 0 and 255 inclusive
#   @param green [Number]
#     A number between 0 and 255 inclusive
#   @param blue [Number]
#     A number between 0 and 255 inclusive
#   @param alpha [Number]
#     A number between 0 and 1
#   @return [Color]
#
# @overload rgba(color, alpha)
#   Sets the opacity of a color.
#
#   @example
#     rgba(#102030, 0.5) => rgba(16, 32, 48, 0.5)
#     rgba(blue, 0.2)    => rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)
#
#   @param color [Color]
#   @param alpha [Number]
#     A number between 0 and 1
#   @return [Color]
def rgba(*args)
  case args.size
  when 2
    color, alpha = args

    assert_type color, :Color
    assert_type alpha, :Number

    Sass::Util.check_range('Alpha channel', 0..1, alpha)
    color.with(:alpha => alpha.value)
  when 4
    red, green, blue, alpha = args
    rgba(rgb(red, green, blue), alpha)
  else
    raise ArgumentError.new("wrong number of arguments (#{args.size} for 4)")
  end
end
declare :rgba, [:red, :green, :blue, :alpha]
declare :rgba, [:color, :alpha]
```

The `rgb()` function must have exactly 3 arguments.  The `rgba()` function must have exactly 2 or 4 arguments with the last argument being a value between 0 and 1.